# execute Shortcut on terminal mac os x

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

I have an application on another mac as mine, the software is still open, there are keyboard shortcuts that allow to perform tasks, I would like to execute shortcuts via the terminal from my mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript. For example if it was TextEdit;

Edit a file say `command` and type in
`tell application "TextEdit"
 activate
   tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {command down}
   end tell 
 end tell`

Then run 
`osascript command`.